# Special charcter issue at Mysql to CSV in PHP script

Tags: php

I am trying to create a .csv file from a php script (that get the data from a database). My problem is that special characters are not displayed correctly.

```
    $content[] = All field content at here.

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($content);

$title = array("Category", "ProductName", "ProductSKU", "Price", "ProductURL", "ManufacturerSKU", "ManufacturerName","EAN","Description"
,"imageURL","StockStatus","DeliveryTime","Shippingcost");

$output = fopen('csv.csv', 'w+');
fputcsv($output, $title);
foreach ($content as $con) {
    fputcsv($output, $con);
}
fclose($output);
echo "CSV created."
```

When i print $content, it is displaying properly special characters, But when i open csc.csv, It is not displaying properly.

Comment: Which character set are you using? What do you use to open it?

Comment: I have set `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` at file begining

Comment: A CSV file has no such header. Perhaps a BOM might work, otherwise, it is up to the program that reads the CSV to decide which character set it uses.

Comment: Can you provide me any link or example for this? What should i do?

Comment: Your best bet is not to use CSV. If you export to a certain application, you can try several libraries to export to XLSX or ODS. Another solution is to make sure you export as UTF-8 and instruct the user of the CSV to import it correctly.

Comment: I have detect encoding string type of special character variable with,
`$content[] = utf8_encode($new);
echo mb_detect_encoding($new);exit;`
and it returns ASCII.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71761/discussion-between-urjit-gandhi-and-bart-friederichs).

Comment: With the help of,
`$content = html_entity_decode($new);`
I got Partially succes.
But some characters are not decoding.